# Как мне к модели прицепить вновь созданный файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, watermark

Пользователь добавляет видео и автоматически на видео накладывается водяной знак.
Обработать видео пользователя и **поставить водяной знак получается**, а **как это видео к модели прицепить не знаю, чтоб потом это видео с водяным знаком на сайте отображалось.** Просто прикрепить к модели obj.video_uploaded = final_ - не получается, пишет ошибка object has no attribute '_committed'

model.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d')
    video_uploaded = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py

```
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VideoUploaderForm(
            data=request.POST,
            files=request.FILES,
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            vid = request.FILES['video_uploaded']
            clip = VideoFileClip(vid.temporary_file_path())
            # watermark
            video = VideoFileClip(clip.filename)
            logo = (ImageClip('faiklogo.png')
                    .set_duration(video.duration)
                    .resize(height=50)
                    .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
                    .set_pos(("center", "bottom")))
            final_ = CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
            final_.write_videofile('media/video/videwithwatermark.mp4')
            obj.save()
    else:
        form=VideoUploaderForm()
    return render(request, 'firstapp/add_video.html', {"foenter code hererm": form})
```

form.py

```
class VideoUploaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: `final_.save()` ?

Comment: 'CompositeVideoClip' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: тогда `obj.video_uploaded.path = 'media/video/videwithwatermark.mp4'; obj.save()` , но путь тогда нужно ставить относительно папки `MEDIA_ROOT` и название уникальное должно быть (если новый файл)

Comment: Ошибка: can't set attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332443/set-djangos-filefield-to-an-existing-file)

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = FileField(upload_to=get_document_path)
    description = CharField(max_length=100)


doc = Document()
doc.file.name = 'path/to/file'  # must be relative to MEDIA_ROOT
doc.file
<FieldFile: path/to/file>
```

То есть в вашем случае это будет так:

```py
obj.video_uploaded.name = 'video/videwithwatermark.mp4'
# obj.video_uploaded.save()  # Если не сохранится
obj.save()
```

Comment: Не помнил параметр, который нудно менять чтобы заменить файл

Comment: если obj.video_uploaded.name = 'video/videwithwatermark.mp4' obj.save() то файл к модели не прикрепляется, прикрепляется только обыяное видео без водяного знака                    
  если obj.video_uploaded.save() ошибка:                                                         
save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'content'            если obj.video_uploaded.save(name = 'something', content = 'video/videwithwatermark.mp4') ошибка:
 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: если прикрепляется, значит файл  не тот прикрепляете

Comment: да нет, прикрепляется тот файл который пользователь добавляет, без водяного знака, видео с водяным знаком не прикряпляется

Answer (score 0):

Получилось методом тыка!!!

```
obj.video_uploaded = 'videwithwatermark.mp4'
obj.save()
```